# Migrate model from a VS 2015 to VS 2010

Tags: codefluent

I initially created the Codefluent project for Visual Studio 2015 but now need to drop it down to Visual Studio 2010. The documentation states that an existing database or model can be imported. It's not clear what is meant by importing an existing model. I assumed the import wizard would give me an option to specify the .cfp file (which is essentialy my model) that I created in Visual Studio 2015. I don't see any such option. The only import option I see is to specify the connection string to the database and then specify the tables.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to do an import by specifying the .cfp instead of the database and tables to be imported?
2. If there is no import option on the .cfp file, I'll probably manually copy and paste the contents of the .cfp from the VS2015 project into .cfp file of the VS2010 project. Does that seem like a good solution?

Comment: I ended up using option 2. One thing to note, when opening a cfp file that does not have any entities in it the producers are not configured inside the cfp. I added a dummy entity called test1 using the models GUI. This added the configuration for the producers to the .cfp. After doing this I pasted the contents from the VS 2015. Things seem to be working and life is good again.

Comment: .cfxproj files (the ones open by Visual Studio) are just almost empty files that point to the root .cfp. So, regarding the model, cfxproj are compatible with all versions of Visual Studio from 2008 to 2015.